# Android Music player in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, media-player

I have developed a music player app in kotlin language. At present when I start another app's song, my app's song is also playing. both songs are playing simultaneously. I would like to add a functionality where the song should stop automatically when another app's media (audio/video) starts playing. How to add this functionality. What concept is behind it? Any hint or suggestion would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this Documentation, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#audio-focus-change. where you will be given the option to add listener in the AudioFocusRequest Builder
to listen to Audio Focus Event and add your callback there.
alternatively `ExoPlayer` Library gives you the option to handle Audio Focus automatically on `setAudioAttributes` method on its `Player` implementation

Comment: thanks man...highly appreciate it..